# Showing part of html "responsive"

Tags: html, responsive

I am very beginner.
And I want to show `div class y` if `media screen width = 1000px`.
And display `div x` if `media screen width = 720px`.

What should I do ؟  "responsive"

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="x" ></div>
    <div class="y" ></div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: What have you done/attempted to try and achieve what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are CSS media queries. This is an example from the requirements of your post. Hide the divs by default. Show `.x` if the viewport width is 720px, show `.y` if the viewport is 1000px.

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

@media (width: 1000px) {
  .y {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (width: 720px) {
  .x {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="x" >x</div>
    <div class="y" >y</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.x {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.y
{width:200px;
height:200px;
background:black;}
@media (max-width:1000px) and (min-width:721px)
{
 .x
 {
  display:none;
  }
}
@media (max-width:720px) and (min-width:640px)
{
 .y
 {
  display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="x" ></div><div class="y" ></div>
<!--resize the browser size-->
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make a web page responsive by adding media queries. The general syntax to be used on style sheet is:
*@media [conditions]{
   styles
}*

To make div y work at 1000px or more and to hide div x, add the following query in your style sheet:

```
@media (min-device-width:1000px){
   .y{display:block;}
   .x{display:none;}
}
```

To make div x work at 750px or less and to hide div y, make use of the following:

```
@media (max-device-width:750px){
   .x{display:block;}
   .y{display:none;}
}
```

Both these statements must be there in the style sheet. Also, 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0">` must be added to your html above the *body* tag.

In order to specify a piece of code for a mobile device use the query,

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:500px) and min-device-width:200px){
      //The values used in pixels is just an example. It can vary..
    }
```